# Code Documentation in Dart

Tags: dart

Do we have any code documentation syntax and tool support for generating Code Documentation out of Dart Application Code, something similar to Doxygen for C/C++.  I prefer to use Markdown styled syntax than doxygen-syntax.

Comment: What's wrong with the official `dartdoc` tool? It generates APIs for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DartDoc tool (which uses markdown) creates API documentation (as found at [api.dartlang.org](http://api.dartlang.org) )

[This](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dartdoc.html) describes the api reference for using DartDoc in your own code

The [Readme.txt here](http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/pkg/dartdoc/README.txt), shows how you can format your code comments to generate API doc

Comment: A couple of the links are broken. For "This", I don't know if we generate dartdoc for dartdoc any more. Maybe delete that paragraph. For the Readme.txt, perhaps substitute a link to https://www.dartlang.org/articles/doc-comment-guidelines/. You might also want to link to https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dartdoc.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
///I am the beerclass
class BeerClass{
  ///this is a beer variable
  String beername;

  ///this is a beer method
  String get getBeer => "beer for the people";
}
```

Just go in the Darteditor: **Tools->Generate Dartdoc**. You get a new directory `docs` and you start index.html in your browser. Your class, variable and method have now documentation.